# JAXB marshalling in WebSphere 8.5.5.3 results in elements from an interface in the SOAP response XML

Tags: java, tomcat, interface, jaxb, websphere-8

We have a web service that uses JAXB to marshal and unmarshal the SOAP request and response.  We are using Sun/Oracle JDK7 on Tomcat and the corresponding IBM JDK7 on WebSphere 8.5.5.3.  The application runs as expected on Tomcat, however the unmarshalling response from WebSphere results in a null object due to an extra element from the Java Interface that the class implements - in the response XML.
The sample Java dynamic web service project was created in Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2) to reproduce the object marshalling error while returning a class that extends an abstract class, which returns an interface in WebSphere.  The project is structured in following manner:

- Person.java - Person is an interface.
- Employee.java - Employee is a class that implements Person interface.
- Manager.java - Manager is a class that extends Employee class.
- Department.java - This is an abstract class that contains an abstract method getPerson(), which returns a Person interface.
- Finance.java - [This is a class that extends Department, which polymorphs a getPerson() method to return a Manager object.]
- PersonnelEndPoint.java - [This is an endpoint of the Personnel web service, that contains a method getFinanceDepartment(), which returns Finance object]

Notice that there is an extra element `<person>` in the XML returned from WebSphere below.  **Is there an option in WebSphere that suppresses returning an element from a base interface?**

The SoapUI capture from the application deployed in Tomcat is as follows:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:getFinanceDepartmentResponse xmlns:ppl="http://personnel.corporate.org" xmlns:ns3="http://application.corporate.org/">
         <return>
            <manager>
               <firstName>Austin</firstName>
               <internalId>1000</internalId>
               <lastName>Smith</lastName>
               <middleName>J</middleName>
               <level>1</level>
               <managerYn>true</managerYn>
            </manager>
         </return>
      </ns3:getFinanceDepartmentResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The result from WebSphere is as following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:getFinanceDepartmentResponse xmlns:ppl="http://personnel.corporate.org" xmlns:ns2="http://application.corporate.org/">
         <return>
            <manager>
               <firstName>Austin</firstName>
               <internalId>1000</internalId>
               <lastName>Smith</lastName>
               <middleName>J</middleName>
               <level>1</level>
               <managerYn>true</managerYn>
            </manager>
            <person>
               <firstName>Austin</firstName>
               <internalId>1000</internalId>
               <lastName>Smith</lastName>
               <middleName>J</middleName>
               <level>1</level>
               <managerYn>true</managerYn>
            </person>
         </return>
      </ns2:getFinanceDepartmentResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sample java files:

Personnel.java

```
package org.corporate.personnel;
import java.io.Serializable;

// this is a base interface.

public interface Person extends Cloneable, Serializable{
    public Long getInternalId();
    public String getFirstName();
    public String getLastName();
    public String getMiddleName();
}
```

Employee.java

```
package org.corporate.personnel;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.corporate.personnel.Person;
import org.corporate.personnel.Manager;

// Employee class implements Person interface.

@XmlType(name="Employee")
@XmlSeeAlso({Manager.class})
public class Employee implements Person {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2019814652839014485L;

    private Long internalId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private Manager manager;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(Long pInternalId, String pFirstName, String pLastName, 
            String pMiddleName) {
        internalId = pInternalId;
        firstName = pFirstName;
        lastName = pLastName;
        middleName = pMiddleName;
    }

    public Long getInternalId() {
        return internalId;
    }

    public void setInternalId(Long internalId) {
        this.internalId = internalId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```

Manager.java

```
package org.corporate.personnel;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.corporate.personnel.Employee;

// this class inherits Employee class, which implements Person interface.

@XmlType(name = "Manager")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Manager")
public class Manager extends Employee {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1750217675821392021L;

    private Long managerId;
    private Integer level;
    private Boolean managerYn;
    private List<Manager> alternateManagers;
    private List<Employee> subordinates;

    public Long getManagerId() {
        return managerId;
    }

    public void setManagerId(Long managerId) {
        this.managerId = managerId;
    }

    public Integer getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(Integer level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Boolean getManagerYn() {
        return managerYn;
    }

    public void setManagerYn(Boolean managerYn) {
        this.managerYn = managerYn;
    }

    public List<Manager> getAlternateManagers() {
        return alternateManagers;
    }

    public void setAlternateManagers(List<Manager> alternateManagers) {
        this.alternateManagers = alternateManagers;
    }

    public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
        return subordinates;
    }

    public void setSubordinates(List<Employee> subordinates) {
        this.subordinates = subordinates;
    }
}
```

Department.java

```
package org.corporate.personnel;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name="Department")
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso({Manager.class, Finance.class})
public abstract class Department implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    // eclipse auto generated serial version 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -910358057883859853L;

    // references Person interface.
    public abstract Person getPerson();
}
```

Finance.java

```
package org.corporate.personnel;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "Finance")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Finance")
public class Finance extends Department {
    // eclipse auto generated serial version 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4012667746961776179L;
    private Manager manager;

    // note: the getPerson method returns Person interface.
    // Manager is a class that extends Employee class, which implements Person
    // interface.

    // implements getPerson method from abstract class.
    public Manager getPerson() {
        return manager;
    }
    public void setPerson(Manager pManager) {
        manager = pManager;
    }
    public Manager getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
    public void setManager(Manager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }
}
```

PersonnelEndPoint.java

```
package org.corporate.application;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.corporate.personnel.Finance;
import org.corporate.personnel.Manager;

/**
 * This sample application demonstrates WebSphere returns 
 * properties from an interface. 
 * @author EXL Landa
 *
 */
@WebService
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso({Manager.class, Finance.class})
public class PersonnelEndPoint {    
    /**
     * The public method that returns an interface implemented
     * in a base class Department.
     * @return
     */
    @WebMethod
    public Finance getFinanceDepartment() {
        Finance lFinance = new Finance();
        lFinance.setPerson(getManager());
        return lFinance;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a local manager object.
     * @return Manager
     */
    private Manager getManager() {
        Manager lManager = new Manager();
        lManager.setInternalId(1000L);
        lManager.setFirstName("Austin");
        lManager.setMiddleName("J");
        lManager.setLastName("Smith");
        lManager.setLevel(1);
        lManager.setManagerYn(true);
        return lManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on WASv8009 and it did not work.  There may be a difference how Tomcat and WebSphere process webservices, but your Finance class will return 2 complex types.  The org.corporate.application.jaxws does nothing in WAS.  To achieve what you want add @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) to the Finance class.

This is from SoapUI after I made the change: 

   
      
         
            
               Austin
               1000
               Smith
               J
               1
               true

Answer (score 0):

Please try suggestions made in below link you may want to add @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) and give it a try

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=971e1192-7825-49e7-bce8-af2802c1967d

Comment: Hi Krishna, welcome to SO. Usually, it is recommended to provide some information in addition to  a link because if some day the link is broken, the answer won't be useful anymore. Please edit this answer when you get a chance to provide some details as appropriate.